# What do the Two Mountains Represent in Daniel 2:35 & 45?

Tags: prophecy, daniel

**Daniel 2:33-35 (NASB)**

> 34 You continued looking until a stone was cut out without hands, and it struck the statue on its feet of iron and clay and crushed them. 35 Then the iron, the clay, the bronze, the silver and the gold were crushed all at the same time and became like chaff from the summer threshing floors; and the wind carried them away so that not a trace of them was found. But the stone that struck the statue became a great mountain and filled the whole earth.

**Daniel 2:44-45 (NASB)**

> 44 In the days of those kings the God of heaven will set up a kingdom which will never be destroyed, and that kingdom will not be left for another people; it will crush and put an end to all these kingdoms, but it will itself endure forever. 45 Inasmuch as you saw that a stone was cut out of the mountain without hands and that it crushed the iron, the bronze, the clay, the silver and the gold, the great God has made known to the king what will take place in the future; so the dream is true and its interpretation is trustworthy.

**The two mountains :**

In verse 45 we read  that a stone was cut of the mountain without the aid of hands, and in verse 35 that the stone that crushed the image, itself became a great mountain.

So, what do these "two mountains" represent?

Comment: A question born of keen observation, the meditative study of scripture and a high IQ. +1

Comment: The two mountains are two kingdoms.  But the two kingdoms are alike. We know that God rules in heaven. But his will is not being done on earth as it is in heaven. So out of his heavenly kingdom, an earthly civilization will be born. That's going to be the kingdom of his Messiah.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note: All my scriptural references are from the NKJV. The bold texts are the headings under which my path to an answer are carved.

a) **The first Mountain in Daniel 2:44-45 represents God and his Kingdom**

> Deuteronomy 32:15  " But Jeshurun grew fat and kicked; You grew fat,
>   you grew thick, You are obese! Then he forsook God [who] made him, And
>   **scornfully esteemed the Rock of his salvation**.
>
> Deuteronomy 32:18  **Of the Rock [who] begot you, you are unmindful,** And
>   have forgotten the God who fathered you.
>
> Deuteronomy 32:19  " And when the LORD saw it, He spurned them,
>   Because of the provocation of His sons and His daughters.
>
> Deuteronomy 32:30  How could one chase a thousand, And two put ten
>   thousand to flight, **Unless their Rock had sold them**, And the LORD had
>   surrendered them?
>
> Deuteronomy 32:31  **For their rock is not like our Rock**, Even our
>   enemies themselves being judges.

Mountains in scripture are symbolic of kingdoms. This is because the capital cities of almost all ancient kingdoms were founded on mountains. 
Daniel 9:16 clearly illustrates this fact: “Let now Your anger and Your wrath turn away from **Your city Jerusalem, Your holy mountain**.” Throughout the Bible there are tons of examples in which mountains mean cities (Psalms 2:6; 48:1; Isaiah 66:20; Jeremiah 51:25; and Joel 3:17) e.g

- Mount Seir was the site of Bozrah the capital of Edom.
- Mount Sion was the capital of Israel in Jerusalem.

> Revelation 17:9  "Here is the mind which has wisdom: The **seven heads
>   are seven mountains** on which the woman sits.   "**There are also
>   seven kings**. Five have fallen, one is, and the other has not yet
>   come. And when he comes, he must continue a short time.

b) **How the symbol of mountains relate with Nebuchadnezzar's image**

Mountains are composites of all that exists on earth. Iron, copper, gold, silver etc are dug out of mountains. Earth is a product of the decay of mountains. So the first mountain in this prophecy (Daniel 2:44-45) is the source or parent from which all the kingdoms in Nebuchadnezzar's image were born. 
This is the Rock of ages and its king is the Ancient of days.

c) **The Stone cut out of the mountain is a symbol of Christ according to OT and NT prophecy**

The stone cut out of the mountain is the stone that will be used to build the mountain of the Lord's house.

> Isaiah 2:2  Now it shall come to pass in the latter days that the
>   **mountain of the LORD's house Shall be established on the top of the
>   mountains,** And shall be exalted above the hills; And all nations shall
>   flow to it.
>
> Ephesians 2:20-21  having been built on the foundation of the apostles
>   and prophets, Jesus Christ Himself being the **chief cornerstone** in whom
>   the whole building, being joined together, grows into a holy temple in
>   the Lord,

this stone:

> Matthew 21:42  Jesus said to them, "Have you never read in the
>   Scriptures: 'The stone which the builders rejected Has become the
>   **chief cornerstone**. This was the LORD's doing, And it is marvelous in
>   our eyes'?
>
> Isaiah 28:16  Therefore thus says the Lord GOD: "Behold, I lay in Zion
>   a **stone for a foundation**, A tried stone, a **precious cornerstone**, a
>   sure foundation; Whoever believes will not act hastily.
>
> Zechariah 4:7  'Who are you, O **great mountain**? Before Zerubbabel you 
>   shall become a plain! And he shall bring forth the **capstone** With
>   shouts of "Grace, grace to it!"

**In Summary**

So the first mountain is the kingdom of God. The stone cut out of that mountain is Christ's earthly kingdom which will grow into a mountain; a final and an eternal world empire

> Isaiah 9:7  Of the **increase of His government and peace there will
>   be no end,** Upon the throne of David and over His kingdom, To order it
>   and establish it with judgment and justice From that time forward,
>   even forever. The zeal of the LORD of hosts will perform this.

Comment: user 20490 a very good answer may I add Isaiah 65:25 and Isaiah 25:6-9

Comment: @O.Nicolas Thanks. You observation is keen. Not every Christian would notice that there are two different mountains in the passage.

Comment: Perfect! Very good answer. Upvoted +1.

Comment: All fine, except not so keen on the summary statement "an eternal world empire", which raises thoughts of a domination of this world by Christians.  I'd prefer God's kingdom will be brought to earth by the Rock, Christ Jesus, and this kingdom consisting of those who choose to belong, largely by means of suffering persecution, will grow until it is finally established when Christ returns the second and final time. The point about the statue and the mountain is that the mountain is so very different.  Christ's kingdom is never forced upon anyone, it is won by self-sacrificing love.

Answer (score 1):

### What do the Two Mountains represent in Daniel 2:35 & 45?

"A stone was cut out of" a mountain without hands (Dan 2:45), crushed the statue but itself "became a great mountain and filled the whole earth" (Dan 2:35). The immediate context explains these symbols to a large extent:

The phrase “without hands” points to supernatural intervention.

The stone struck the statue on its feet (Dan 2:34). The feet represent the last part of the time or series of kingdoms symbolized by the statue.

It crushed the entire statue so that not a trace of it was found. In Revelation, we similarly read that He who sits on the throne said, “Behold, I am making all things new” (Rev 21:5).

But the stone became a great mountain that filled the whole earth (Dan 2:34-35). So, a stone can become a mountain. A stone is a small mountain. Since they are able to grow, both a stone and a mountain are living things.

In the vision, the stone crushes the statue but, in the explanation of the vision, “a kingdom” which God will set up will crush and put an end to all these kingdoms (Dan 2:44). So, **the stone is this eternal kingdom which God will set up**. The stone is not Christ. The stone is Christ only indirectly in the sense that Daniel frequently uses the terms “king” and “kingdom” interchangeably. For example:

1. The head of gold is identified as Nebuchadnezzar (Dan 2:37) but “after" Nebuchadnezzar "there will arise another kingdom” (Dan 2:39). So, Nebuchadnezzar represents the Babylonian empire.
2. The four beasts in Daniel 7 are explained as four “**kings**” (Dan 7:17) but the fourth is explained as “a fourth **kingdom** on the earth” (Dan 7:23).

Since the stone is a kingdom, and since the stone becomes a great mountain, **the great mountain also symbolizes a kingdom**. It follows that **both mountains in these verses are kingdoms**:

> The stone that became a great mountain “filled the whole earth” (Dan
> 2:35). This, then, is the eternal kingdom that God will establish on
> earth, and which He will rule through “His Christ:”
>
> - “The kingdom of the world has become the kingdom of our Lord and of His Christ; and He will reign forever and ever” (Rev 11:15)
> - “The Ancient of Days” gave to “One like a Son of Man” “dominion, glory and a kingdom, That all the peoples, nations and men of every
>   language Might serve Him” (Dan 7:13-14).
>
> The mountain from which the stone was cut off then seems to refer to
> “the kingdom of God;” a phrase that Jesus used. It always exists but
> is invisible to human eyes. For example:
>
> - “If I cast out demons by the Spirit of God, then **the kingdom of God** has come upon you” (Matt 12:28).
> - “**The kingdom of God** is not coming with signs to be observed … For behold, the kingdom of God is in your midst” (Luke 17:20-21).

Comment: Not bad at all. Pretty darn good in fact. +1.

Comment: @OldeEnglish Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The kingdom of heaven is the first mountain. Christ is the small stone removed from the kingdom of heaven without the work of human hands.
He crushes the worldly kingdoms and establishes a new kingdom. The kingdom of God amongst humanity. This is the holy mountain, His Church. A living tabernacle for the living God, come down from heaven.
He is the cornerstone.

Comment: Hello and welcome to the site! How do you know this what Daniel was referring to? Can you please [edit] this post to add your reasoning and any evidence you have for your interpretation.

Comment: A good and precise answer Pat. Tks

Answer (score -1):

The stone being cut out from a mountain without human hands is our robotic machinery emerging from our modern tech kingdom. Computer chips are literally cut from a [boule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boule_(crystal)), a single silicon crystal stone without using human hands. The boule even looks like a mountain when formed.

[image: Silicon Boule]

[Quantum CPUs made from diamond](https://physicsworld.com/a/the-diamond-quantum%E2%80%AFrevolution/) have been developed. Diamonds are stones too. The symbology of "a stone cut from a mountain" is present in [diamond cutting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond_cutting) as well.

[image: Diamond Crystal]

The imagery of the human statue mostly being made of metal is also a hint. The collapse of the human form onto the floor doubly so.

[image: Dream Statue of Nebuchadnezzar]

This also suggests that the tech we're making is arriving to free our souls from the bonds of the material world. The wind carrying the chaff away is a subtle way of saying our concepts of wealth, trade and food will vanish without a trace.

[image: Matrix Machine City]

The horrific image shown in the Matrix by Morpheus to Neo of the machines filling the whole Earth more or less is what the little "stone" became. For all we know, that may be the "Kingdom of God". A little grim, but who are we humans to really say what our evolutionary path should be to reach the source.

But....this is just an interpretation of an interpretation of a dream which itself is a human interpretation of the spirit world.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).